# UILocalNotification callback not called if you don't define alertBody

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

```
UILocalNotification *soundNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
soundNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
soundNotification.soundName = @"alarm.mp3";
soundNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
soundNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
soundNotification.alertBody = @"alarm is ringing"; //commenting out this line stop callback.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:soundNotification];
```

The problem is that I don't want to define an alertBody for a notification. But still hit the callback

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(nonnull UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Because If I don't hit the callback the sound of the notification cannot be stopped even if you call

```
- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;
```

Is there a way to stop UILocalNotification sound without defining alertBody for the notification?

Comment: soundNotification.alertBody = @" "; //try this

Comment: same result, can't get the callback with that